# How to link social media icons without text inside WordPress post?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Is it possible to link Social media icons inside WordPress post without text?

I have used below code in WordPress Visual composer text module:

```
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/xyz/"><i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
<a href="https://plus.google.com/xyz"><i class="fa fa-google-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
<a href="https://twitter.com/xyz"><i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
<a href="https://www.instagram.com/xyz/"><i class="fa fa-instagram" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
```

After updating the post, the links changed as:

```
<i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i>
<i class="fa fa-google-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i>
<i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i>
<i class="fa fa-instagram" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```

Comment: I think visual composer already has the option to create social icons. Have you tried that?

Answer (score 1):

Can you try with Raw HTML module in the visual composer?

Answer (score 1):

Ideally you'd want to create a shortcode and insert it using VC
Create the shortcode like this:

```
function social_media_shortcode( $atts, $content ) {
    $a = shortcode_atts( array(
    ), $atts );
    ob_start();
    ?>
    <div class="vc-social-media">
        social items go here
    </div>
    <?php
    return ob_get_clean();
}
add_shortcode( 'social-media', 'social_media_shortcode' );
```

Then register the shortcode in VC like this:

```
add_action( 'vc_before_init', 'socialMediaVC' );
function socialMediaVC() {
    vc_map( array(
        "name" => "My Social Media Shortcode",
        "base" => "vc-social-media",
        "class" => "vc-social-media",
        "category" => "Content",
        "params" => array(

        )
    ));
}
```

Now you'll have your own Visual Composer object that you can add.
Also, are you using VC for Posts or for Pages?

Comment: For wordpress pages